# Understanding Lewis Carroll's argument on Modus Ponens

Tags: logic

I read in an answer somewhere on this site that Modus Ponens involves an infinite regress.

Upon reading Lewis Carroll's Achilles and the tortoise, I fail to see how.

This is the excerpt from wikipedia where I am confused:

```
A: "Things that are equal to the same are equal to each other"   
B: "The two sides of this triangle are things that are equal to the same"
Therefore, 
Z: "The two sides of this triangle are equal to each other"
```

> The Tortoise then asks Achilles whether a second kind of reader might
>   exist, who accepts that A and B are true, but who does not yet accept
>   the principle that if A and B are both true, then Z must be true.

If A and B are true, I think it follows logically that Z is true, and there are no more steps in between where one might disagree.
Could someone please point out what i'm not able to follow?

Z must be true if A and B both are held true.

Comment: You feel that our logic rules are absolutely true, but they are not. Like how you can't see *new* color, you can't think outside of our logic rules. But this does not mean other colors do not exist.

Comment: See [What the Tortoise Said to Achilles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_the_Tortoise_Said_to_Achilles) for overview and references.

Comment: The infinite regress sketched by LC's article is based on the indubitable fact that in explaining/presenting/elucidating the concept of "valid inference" we have to use logical connectives and logical arguments.

Comment: @mauroallegranza I read the wiki page, but im still not quite getting it. As far as i can see we are using logical arguments

Comment: Simple example: how we ground *modus ponens* ? Basically with the truth-table for "if..., then..." and the def of *valid argument*. How is defined "valid argument" ? With e.g. "**if** the premises are true, **then** the conclusion is true". This, in a nutshell, is the infinite regress on which LC based is celebrated dialogue.

Comment: @mauroallegranza if you could elaborate this in an answer, I'd happily accept it. I still fail to see the infinite regress.

Comment: You say: “If A and B are true, […] Z is true”. The tortoise doesn’t deny this and grants (C). Yet this only gets you another *true statement*, one that is distinct from (Z). In general, the method only generates an ever-growing list of true statements, but never the conclusion. So, we can go on forever without reaching the conclusion. In that sense, it’s an ‘infinite regress’ – although the term ‘regress’ may not seem entirely appropriate. (I don’t think Lewis uses it.)

Comment: You also say: “there are no more steps in between”; but note that we haven’t really taken any *steps*: we’ve only generated a further premise. That’s part of Lewis’s point, I think: You can’t do proofs with just axioms. You also need *rules of inference* that let you **move** from one claim to another.

Comment: @markoxford so you mean to say that we dony know if z is ever true, because we dont ever know if a and b are true?

Comment: See also Pascal Engel, [DUMMETT, ACHILLES AND THE TORTOISE](https://www.unige.ch/lettres/philo/enseignants/pe/Engel%202007%20Dummett%20Achilles%20and%20the%20Tortoise.pdf).

Comment: “we don’t know if z is ever true, because we don’t ever know if a and b are true” This isn’t about what we know, or about why we believe z (or a or b). It’s not really about what’s true, either: truth is a *semantic* notion, while deductive systems belong in *syntax*. The tortoise says: Force me to accept Z! which I take to mean that the tortoise wants to see a proof. However, an ever-growing list of (true) sentences isn’t a proof, *even if* these sentences semantically entail Z.

Comment: @novice. After this extended set of comments, would it be best to revise the question?